# Bigcommerce Checkout page edit

Tags: checkout, bigcommerce

I am using Valult theme in bigcommerce and want to edit checkout page because i want to rename the a button. I went through all the files but there was no html check i found a tag {{{ checkout.checkout_content }}} in checkout page which is rending that part containing button. There is no file with contains the tag html.  This content is rendered in Inspect element but when i view the source of page the content is not present there.

I tried to change the name of button with JS/JQ but it is not working because that Tag part wont comes in Source file but somehow it is present in inspect element.

How can it edit the Button name now ?

Answer (score 2):

The checkout content is rendered with React.js. The only way to edit the template would be to build a custom checkout. This is probably a bit overkill here. To simply edit the text of a button, you have a few options. However, the simplest would be to just add the translation key to your en.json lang file and change the value to the desired text.

In your theme files, navigate to en.json. Find the end of this file, and right before the last closing brace, add in the optimized_checkout key, along with any values you need. For example, if I wanted to change the "Continue with PayPal" button text to be "Continue", I would replace the last two lines of en.json with the following:

```
    },
    "optimized_checkout": {
        "payment": {
            "paypal_continue_action": "Continue"
        }
    }
}
```

There is more information on how to do this here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/localization/multi-language-checkout

And here is the reference for the optimized checkout keys to use: https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-js/blob/master/src/app/locale/translations/en.json